# How do would you combine Scheduler.animationFrame and fromEvent(window, 'scroll') streams in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, requestanimationframe

I have two observables `Observable.of(0, animationFrame)` & `Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')`.  I want to combine them so that my `renderScrollBar(event)` is only called on the ticks of animationFrame.

```
  Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
      .map((event: any) => event.currentTarget)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this._renderScrollBar(event);
      });
  let x = 0;
  Observable.of(0, animationFrame)
      .repeat()
      .takeUntil(Observable.timer(1000))
      .subscribe(() => console.log(x++));
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to run an action on every animationFrame in RxJS.

Comment: Is [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: @concat I think it is would you be able to make an sample in the answer?  I'll try it out and mark it correct

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to throttle scroll event to requestAnimationFrame you can use `throttleTime(0, animationFrame)` operator instead of `Observable.of(0, animationFrame)`.

Example

```
Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
    .throttleTime(0, animationFrame)
```

**Update:**

RxJS 6

```
import { fromEvent, animationFrameScheduler } from "rxjs";
import { throttleTime } from "rxjs/operators";

fromEvent(window, "scroll")
  .pipe(throttleTime(0, animationFrameScheduler))
```

Comment: I would suggest updating this to RXJS 6, but great answer

Comment: This answer just helped me to finally fix a bug that's been plaguing us for months and has been nearly impossible to track down! Thank you!
We had the `throttleTime` operator further downstream instead of right after `fromEvent` and somehow that was messing things up.

Comment: And if you're interested in the most recent event from the silenced time window, rather than the first one, then I would suggest to use the `auditTime` operator instead of the `throttleTime`.

Answer (score 1):

[`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) is a quick and dirty solution that has a potentially serious flaw: the scroll handler lags behind the true scroll value when scroll events emit faster than the frame rate. It would look something like:

```
Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
          .map(event => event.currentTarget)
          .zip(Observable.of(0, animationFrame)
                         .repeat(),
            (currentTarget, _) => this._renderScrollBar(currentTarget)
          );
```

If you need `event` to contain the very latest scroll information, you might need to resort to a more elaborate solution with [the `window` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/window.md#with-window-closing-selector), like:

```
Observable.fromEvent(window, 'scroll')
          .map(event => event.currentTarget)
          .window(Observable.of(0, animationFrame).repeat())
          .mergeMap(w => w.takeLast(1))
          .subscribe(currentTarget => this._renderScrollBar(currentTarget));
```

1. Foremost, `window` creates a stream of Observable chunks from the source, chunked each time the argument Observable emits an item. In this case, series of scroll events are chunked by each animation tick.
2. We take only the latest from each chunk if the chunk isn't empty, and `mergeMap` that to a flat output stream. Empty chunks won't contribute any items to this final stream.

Comment: it seems to be working but i'm getting an error
EmptyError {name: "EmptyError", stack: "EmptyError: no elements in sequence, message: "no elements in sequence"}
message
:
"no elements in sequence"
name
:
"EmptyError"
stack
:
"EmptyError: no elements in sequence

Comment: @MatthewHarwood My bad, `takeLast(1)` is what you want, as won't throw on empty streams.

Answer (score 1):

```
interval(0)
  .pipe(throttleTime(0, animationFrameScheduler))
  .subscribe(() => {
    fifth++;
  });

scheduled(interval(0), animationFrameScheduler).subscribe(() => {
  sixth++;
});
```

those two seems to be just 1 frame off whatever we set time for 1, 2 or 100 seconds ;)

```
REAL:  181
FIRST:  109
SECOND:  217
THIRD:  108
FOURTH:  217
FIFTH:  180
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Trust the browser!

For the longest time I've used the following in a global service:

```
windowScroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
        map(x => window.scrollY), 
        startWith(0), 
        distinctUntilChanged(), 
        shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }))
```

Decided to do some testing to see if I could improve performance (not that I had any known issue) by using animationFrame.

##### Results:

In my testing in desktop Chrome and iOS Safari I couldn't find **any way** to improve the above by adding animationFrame scheduling.

###### Methodology:

Create a second variation of the above observable, adding `throttleTime` with an  `animationFrameScheduler`. Then subscribe to both and see which reaches 100 emissions first.

```
    let v1 = 0;
    let v2 = 0;

    this.windowScroll$.pipe(tap(() => v1++)).subscribe((t) => { (v1 >= 100) && alert('v1=' + v1 + ', v2=' + v2); });
    this.windowScroll2$.pipe(tap(() => v2++)).subscribe((t) => { (v2 >= 100) && alert('v1=' + v1 + ', v2=' + v2); });
```

I would always get `v1=100, v2=100` demonstrating they were both identical in terms of emission count.

##### Conclusion

The browser **already** only emits a scroll event when the value has changed. It doesn't do this more often than animation frames - and why would it? It wouldn't make any sense to ever do that.

#### How to best handle this:

The number one thing you can do to improve performance is to put your observable in a global (`providedIn: 'root'`) service (notice the `shareReplay`). Then whenever you're using it you'll be referring to the same instance and creating only one browser event. Forget all about animationFrame scheduler.

```
  windowScroll$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
         map(x => window.scrollY), 
         startWith(0), 
         distinctUntilChanged(),
         shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 }));
```

BTW: The `distinctUntilChanged()` is only here to ignore horizontal scrolling (because the y value would remain the same but you'd still get events). If you don't have horizontal scroll bars you'd never notice a difference.

If you're actually performing a complicated action as a result, then use `throttleTime`, or `debounceTime` depending upon your exact needs. AnimationFrame won't help you here.

```
 // immediately emit when scroll starts, then report at most every 500ms
 service.windowScroll$.pipe(throttleTime(500, { leading: true, trailing: true })).subscribe(...)
```